# catalina.policy file permission with '#' character

Tags: java, tomcat8

I'm deploying a war file named **foo#bar.war** into tomcat 8.5(which creates a context path /foo/bar once deployed) and i need to set a permission in a jar inside the war. Once deployed the following folder is created under webapps: **foo#bar** and im trying to set the permission in catalina.policy as follows

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}${/}webapps${/}foo#bar${/}WEB-INF${/}lib${/}myjar.jar" {
         permission .......
};
```

However it is not working, what i see while debugging is it is encoding the # character and fails to find the folder in file system. I tried escaping the # but didn't work.

Also tried not unpacking the war and set the permission

```
grant codeBase "file:${/}foo#bar.war!${/}WEB-INF${/}lib${/}myjar.jar" {
         permission .......
};
```

but got the same issue with the #

Is there a way to escape the # character?

Comment: Just as an aside, are you committed to the foo#bar mechanism, or have you considered a custom context.xml for your application?

Comment: If i use foo.war and create context.xml and set context path to /foo/bar in server.xml, the folder created in webapps is named after the context path not the war name, so i end up with the same foor#bar folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:` is an URL. Thus `#` can be encoded as `%23`.

Also I would use simple '/' instead of `${/}`.

For example, with current Tomcat 9.0.x and Java 11 I can do the following with the default Manager web application:

1. Rename `webapps/manager` to `webapps/a#manager`
2. Edit `conf/catalina.policy` by replacing

   ```
   grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/manager/-" {
      ...
      permission org.apache.catalina.security.DeployXmlPermission "manager";
   ```

   with

   ```
   grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/a%23manager/-" {
      ...
      permission org.apache.catalina.security.DeployXmlPermission "a#manager";
   ```
3. Start Apache Tomcat with a Security Manager being enabled (`catalina start -security`)
4. Access `http://localhost:8080/a/manager/html`